# checking for character pair in array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a character array that produces a random array of lowercase letters in the length that the user inputs. my problem is that after the array of random letters is produced the user inputs a pair of charaters(two letters) and my code should check if that pair is in the random array that was produced. it worked fine when it just checked for one letter but when i introduced the second one it does not work.I would appreciate any help.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    std::srand(std::time(NULL));
    int i, num;
    char letter1, letter2, ch, r;
    const char chars[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";


    std::cout << "How many letters do you want in your string? ";
    std::cin >> num;

    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        ch = chars[rand()%26];
        std::cout << ch;
    }

    std::cout << "\nWhat letter pair would you like to find? ";
    std::cin >> letter1 >> letter2;


    if ((chars[i] == letter1) && (chars[i+1]==letter2))
        std::cout << "It is in your string. ";
    else
        std::cout << "You do not have " << letter1 << letter2 << " in your string";
}
```

Comment: If you input the letter pair that you would like to find before the randomly generated string, you shouldn't have to store the randomly generated string. But yes, not storing the randomly generated string (you just keep overwriting `ch` which is one letter) is never going to yield a solution.

You have some of the fundamentals down, but you are also missing a loop to check for the letter pair, and your `chars[i+1]` is likely to go out of bounds and result in undefined behaviour.

It's difficult to know where to start helping without giving away the full answer to your (homework?) question.

Comment: You need to store your random string somewhere before you can check it. Currently you are checking on your "a-z" string and you are not checking your randomly generated string!

Comment: If you read and store `letter1` and `letter2` before you "generate" the random string, you do not need to store the random string.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not storing your randomly generated chars

```
for (i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    ch = chars[rand()%26];
    std::cout << ch;
}
```

This just writes a random char in ch and displays it on the console with each iteration. You don't store your data, ch just contains the last random char after your loop ends and everything else is lost.

The part where you want to search is double wrong.

```
if ((chars[i] == letter1) && (chars[i+1]==letter2))
    std::cout << "It is in your string. ";
else
    std::cout << "You do not have " << letter1 << letter2 << " in your string";
```

1. This isn't inside a loop, i is simply always going to be num-1.
2. The array you are checking is chars which is your const array containing "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz". This doesn't contain your randomly generated chars.

Comment: This isn't really an answer: its more of a (valid) critique, but shouldn't be posted as an answer.

Comment: @Sebastian I pointed out exactly what is wrong and why. You don't have to write  code for someone to answer their question.

Comment: Since there was no actual question except "I would appreciate any help." this is a valid answer in my eyes.

Comment: I'm not trying to be pedantic, but this doesn't qualify as a SO answer and should not be posted in the answers section. I made the same mistake myself a few days ago. An answer would provide an an answer to to the problem, and not simply reasons why the current implementation will fail.

Comment: @Sebastian I recommend you to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. „Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful“. This also makes it very clear that an answer doesn‘t always have to provide a full working solution to the problem to qualify as an answer. An answer is simply supposed to answer the question. In this case the question was for help on why his program isn‘t doing what it is supposed to do. I think this answer provides that.